# How to properly handle the changing of email uids over previous sessions?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, uid

I have a simple server which listen for incoming email messages from one or more folders and from one or more mailboxes.

Downloaded messages (quite all except their bodies and attachments) are persisted in a database, so even their UID and they can be retrieved each time a client want by referencing them by their UID.

I've unfortunately "just" discovered that Mail Servers may renumber some or maybe all their messages, so that renumbering invalidate all my UIDS previously persisted in database.

I'm not understanding what action should I take to overcome this behaviour, this renumbering, what I can do to intercept this renumbering and what can I do to renumber my messages, a part of them or all ?

I have understood the UIDValidity mechanism but I'm not understanding what exactly do when I discover its change.

I was thinking to:

1. For each message in Mail Server
2. Search it in my db, doing match with its subject, date and messageid
3. If found, update message in db with its new UID

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really do anything. Once the IMAP server tells you that the `UIDVALIDITY` has changed, then the only standard-compliant, reliable and safe action is to discard everything from your local cache.

There are some non-standard extensions which might help you. GMail, for example, has its own [`X-GM-MSGID`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid), but it doesn't specify whether these get invalidated upon an `UIDVALIDITY` change.

There were some efforts among the Courier and Dovecot maintainers to standardize a `DIGEST` extension for computing cryptographic hashes of individual messages. These would be exactly what you're looking for. However, I don't think these ever got standardized. Also, keep in mind that the MIME standard allows for several equivalent representations of any given message (think various 8bit encoding schemes). Any body digesting breaks once the MIME structure changes.

I would not attempt to use the `Message-Id` if I were you. Its value is user-controlled.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I'm interested in finding all possible causes of such events, @Max wrote some of them but I would like to know if there are more, do you know?

In my scenario, I'm quite sure that "my" folders were not renamed, so their messages are always the same I previously downloaded.
For this reason I would implement a solution that searchs for persisted messages using <messageid, date, subject> of messages just read from mail server and that if finds them, set the new UID.
I would like to know if you think it is a foolishness, thanks

Comment: It is a bad idea, because all of those fields are controlled by the sender; it is also perfectly allowable to have duplicates in a folder (eg, a copy).

Comment: @Gamby, if you need some locally unique identifier, then your only reasonably safe method is computing a cryptographic hash of the e-mail content. However, that will not prevent possible duplicated messages; it's perfectly OK to have two messages which only differ in some small tecnnical detail of their transport serialization (i.e., MIME).

Answer (score 1):

Generally `UIDVALIDITY` should not change.  If it does, you should do a full resynchronization of that folder (delete everything and sync from zero).

If it does change, this may mean it is actually a different folder.  For example, delete a folder and rename a different folder to the name of the old folder.  Or delete the folder or recreate a new one with the same name.  Same name, different folder, different `UIDVALIDITY`.